How to force Entity Framework to treat variable as constant?
I have an EF6 IQueryable<T> which contains a variable in a where clause. I have performance issues with parameter sniffing because the execution plans for some variable values are very inefficient for others. I have contemplated solutions to this issue like adding OPTION (RECOMPILE) to the query but I don't really like that.
I would prefer if I could force EF6 to just treat this specific variable as a constant and create a separate execution plan for each value (its an Int which can have one of 5 different values).
The Linq that creates the variable in the query looks like this:
query = query.Where(x => x.DBColumn == abc); //abc is an int variable

Thanks!
Edit: I'm using MS SQL Server 2016

This won't help. Parameter sniffing is when the query optimizer sees a constant and turns it into a parameter. You still need OPTION(RECOMPILE) to avoid this and you still need to find out why the execution plans are bad - missing indexes? Bad statistics? A flag column that's essentially useless because most values are the same? A filtered index may be a better option in this case. Perhaps the flag column should be split into 5 separate columns, combined with filtered indexes

The execution plans are bad because my database table contains very few values for some of the variable's values and many more for others. So the data isn't evenly distributed and when the cached execution plan is based on a variable value with few entries it performs terribly slowly for other variable values.

Sql Server 2022 introduced Parameter Sensitive Plan optimization

You mentioned that already, and I already answered that. You need OPTION RECOMPILE to prevent the constant from being treated as a parameter. You can also use OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@ProductID=945)); to ask for a plan optimizing for specific values. Brent Ozar explains this option and several others in his  parameter sniffing articles while Erland Sommarskog  goes deep into how to troubleshoot such problems with various techniques, including INCLUDE, filtered indexes, hints

I was thinking it could be possible to use ConstantExpression from System.Linq.Expressions to dynamically create a query for each possible value of my variable. But I cannot get it figured out and not 100% sure it is possible. That would be my ideal solution.

Solving the real problem depends on the actual query, actual column, its values and how it's used. We can't guess that. OPTION RECOMPILE is a pretty good catch-all option in many cases.

ideal not at all. What you try to do can lead to parameter sniffing. I explained that parameter sniffing is when the database query optimizer turns a constant into a parameter. The optimizer sniffs constants and turns them into parameters, hence parameter sniffing.

If DBColumn isn't selective why include it in an index anyway? Remove it from the index and the bad execution plan, one that performs a Seek for eg half the table, goes away. If you need to speed up queries for the low-frequency values, you can create a filtered index that only applies to the low frequency values eg WHERE DBColumn in (4,5)

In EF Core 8 you can use EF.Constant(abc) to do this. @PanagiotisKanavos sometimes it is actually the right answer to use a constant. For example when filtering by TenantId or some value which heavily skews the data, there is almost nothing you can do otherwise to get the right plan per query.

@Charlieface this won't solve the parameter sniffing problem. It will change the parameterized query to a constant one. The database can still change Where dbcolumn=5 to Where dbcolumn=?.  To avoid sniffing the query still needs RECOMPILE.

@PanagiotisKanavos That would depend on the setting for Forced Parameterization, or if the plan is a Trivial Plan and has no other parameters already in it. If neither are true then automatic parameterization won't happen.

Since the only viable option in EF6 is to add OPTION RECOMPILE, I consider this a duplicate of your question. Please let me know if you agree.

@GertArnold if its really the only viable option, then yes, I guess so.
